# Does a live animal tracking system for vegetarian products exist?

Tags: ethics, commercial-farming, livestock-industry, lacto-ovo-vegetarianism, animal-welfare

I am thinking of a label system on cheese and egg found in supermarkets whereby you can use your phone camera to scan a bar code on those products. It would take you to a live supervision camera system via a standard app whereby you can navigate through the places where the chickens or cows breed, hatch, and give milk.

Via the QR code that could be found on the product, the seller, via agreement with the producers, can be brought to guarantee the cow can be followed, to check up on their health and happiness, and is not killed for meat, or actually not killed at all, not even in old age.

This would allow the direct consumer to envision whether a cow would care to give milk without breeding, or give excess milk, without suffering, and so on, first hand.

My question is: **has this system been implemented anywhere?**

Answer (score 8):

There are no live animal tracking systems like what you describe.

I tried looking for live video streams from farms and I was able to find one [video feed from a farm sanctuary in NY](https://explore.org/livecams/farm-sanctuary/wisconsin-pasture-farm-sanctuary) but of course they don't sell animal products there.

What about abattoirs/slaughterhouses? Although there are plans in the UK to [outfit slaughterhouses with compulsory CCTV](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2017/aug/11/all-slaughterhouses-in-england-to-have-compulsory-cctv) that footage will not be available for public viewing. This appears to be driven by members of the public that are [pressuring supermarkets](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/feb/03/abattoirs-supermarkets-cctv-cruelty-welfare). Similarly there are [plans in France to install CCTV in slaughterhouses](https://www.politico.eu/article/french-parliament-votes-for-slaughterhouses-cameras/).

This question seems to be based on the assumption that some dairy or egg farms do not kill animals even in old age. That is exceedingly rare, almost to the point of non-existence. The answers to these related questions go into more detail.

- [Are there any dairy farms that don't kill cows or calves?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/are-there-any-dairy-farms-that-dont-kill-cows-or-calves?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Are there any farms that don't slaughter older hens?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/are-there-any-farms-that-sell-cruelty-free-eggs-i-e-that-dont-slaughter-old)

In short, no such live animal tracking system exists because the reality is unappealing.

Comment: Amazing, informed, educational answer. Thank you Nic